# Extend text label into one line only?

Tags: css, wordpress

Just created a registration form, and I want to extend a label text to be shown into one line. With CSS inspector found that class is:

```
.rmagic .rmrow .rmfield label
```

and when I insert:

```
width: 600px;
```

It is working fine, but extends all other fields as well, and I just *need the last one*. I set a custom class to that field, called `posledno` but when I insert it into my custom CSS:

```
rmfield.form_1_1-element-18.posledno label {
  widht:600px;
}
```

It doesn't make any changes. How to extend this field ? Page [example](http://echographie-sans-frontieres.com/adherer/) at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I just need the last one

Since you need the last-child of an element, you're better off using the [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) selector.

Here is what would work:

```css
#rm_form_page_form_1_1_1 .rmfieldset .rmrow:last-child .rmfield label {
  width: 600px; 
  background-color: #f00; /** for easier identification */
}
```

Although I would recommend using `%` instead. (relative to the parent element unit)

Comment: Just inserted your CSS, but still see text into 3 lines instead of 1.